# Crashing of application, something to do with Date Diff

Tags: java, android, android-layout, crash

What would be causing this crash to happen, not sure where to look, i have attached the code from the place i think the error is coming from aswell as the error it is throwing out, app works fine, just when i go to one specific section it is crashing with this error.

```
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "null"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.utils.DateUtils.getDiff(DateUtils.java:56)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.activities.OfferDetailActivity.setupOfferDate(OfferDetailActivity.java:509)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.activities.OfferDetailActivity.setupComponents(OfferDetailActivity.java:460)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.activities.OfferDetailActivity.access$200(OfferDetailActivity.java:76)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.activities.OfferDetailActivity$4.onResponse(OfferDetailActivity.java:606)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.activities.OfferDetailActivity$4.onResponse(OfferDetailActivity.java:586)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/oldDate: -62075467800000 - 0002-11-30 00:00:00
E/currentDate: 1629102262245 - 0002-11-30 00:00:00
E/Difference::  seconds: -63704570062 minutes: -1061742834 hours: -17695713 days: -737321
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.buzzr.ca.skeloo, PID: 11310
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1384)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.customView.StoreCardCustomView.updateCategoryBadge(StoreCardCustomView.java:280)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.customView.StoreCardCustomView.setupComponent(StoreCardCustomView.java:263)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.activities.OfferDetailActivity.setupComponents(OfferDetailActivity.java:465)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.activities.OfferDetailActivity.access$200(OfferDetailActivity.java:76)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.activities.OfferDetailActivity$4.onResponse(OfferDetailActivity.java:606)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.activities.OfferDetailActivity$4.onResponse(OfferDetailActivity.java:586)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
I/buzzr.ca.skelo: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 143074(4393KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(268KB) LOS objects, 34% free, 8500KB/12MB, paused 1.171ms total 146.600ms
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11310 SIG: 9
```

I am not really clued up with where to look exactly but i think it has something to do with the date diff. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is OfferDetailActivity.java

```
 /*
         *
         *   DATE & COUNTDOWN
         *
         */

        String date = "";


        try {
            date = mOffer.getDate_start();
            date = DateUtils.prepareOutputDate(date, "dd MMMM yyyy  hh:mm", this);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            syncOffer(offer_id);
            return;

        }

    }


    private void setupComponents(final Offer mOffer) {
        offerData = mOffer;

        getAppBarTitle().setText(mOffer.getName());
        header_title.setText(mOffer.getName());


        if (mOffer.getValue_type().equalsIgnoreCase("Percent") && (mOffer.getOffer_value() > 0 || mOffer.getOffer_value() < 0)) {
            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0");
            badge_price.setText(decimalFormat.format(mOffer.getOffer_value()) + "%");
        } else {
            if (mOffer.getValue_type().equalsIgnoreCase("Price") && mOffer.getOffer_value() != 0) {

                badge_price.setText(OfferUtils.parseCurrencyFormat(
                        mOffer.getOffer_value(),
                        mOffer.getCurrency()));

            } else {
                badge_price.setText(getString(R.string.promo));
            }
        }

        badge_price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (mOffer.getImages() != null)
            Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(mOffer.getImages().getUrl500_500())
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(ImageLoaderAnimation.glideLoader(this))
                    .into(image);


        description_content.setText(mOffer.getDescription());
        new TextUtils.decodeHtml(description_content).execute(mOffer.getDescription());

        Textoo
                .config(description_content)
                .linkifyWebUrls()  // or just .linkifyAll()
                .addLinksHandler(new LinksHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onClick(View view, String url) {

                        if (Utils.isValidURL(url)) {

                            new AwesomeWebView.Builder(OfferDetailActivity.this)
                                    .showMenuOpenWith(false)
                                    .statusBarColorRes(R.color.colorAccent)
                                    .theme(R.style.FinestWebViewAppTheme)
                                    .titleColor(
                                            ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.white, null)
                                    ).urlColor(
                                    ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.white, null)
                            ).show(url);

                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .apply();

        try {

            int cid = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("cid"));
            CampagneController.markView(cid);
            // Toast.makeText(this,"CMarkViewClicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (AppConfig.APP_DEBUG)
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //setup offer date
        setupOfferDate(mOffer);


        if (mOffer.getStore_id() > 0 && StoreController.getStore(mOffer.getStore_id()) != null) {
            Store storeOffers = StoreController.getStore(mOffer.getStore_id());
            customStoreCV.setupComponent(storeOffers);
            updateCategoryBadge(storeOffers.getCategory_name(), storeOffers.getCategory_color());

        } else {

            customStoreCV.loadData(mOffer.getStore_id(), false, new StoreCardCustomView.StoreListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoaded(Store object) {
                    updateCategoryBadge(object.getCategory_name(), object.getCategory_color());
                }
            });

        }


    }

    @SuppressLint("StringFormatMatches")
    private void setupOfferDate(Offer mOffer) {

        String dateStartAt = "";
        String dateEndAt = "";

        try {
            dateStartAt = mOffer.getDate_start();
            dateStartAt = DateUtils.prepareOutputDate(dateStartAt, "dd MMMM yyyy", this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            dateEndAt = mOffer.getDate_end();
            dateEndAt = DateUtils.prepareOutputDate(dateEndAt, "dd MMMM yyyy", this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }

        //        if(mOffer.getType()==0){
//            CountdownView mCvCountdownView = (CountdownView)findViewById(R.id.cv_countdownViewTest1);
//            mCvCountdownView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            typeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//        }else {

        String inputDateSatrt = DateUtils.prepareOutputDate(mOffer.getDate_start(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", this);
        long diff_Will_Start = DateUtils.getDiff(inputDateSatrt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        if (AppConfig.APP_DEBUG) {

            Log.e("_start_at_server", mOffer.getDate_start());
            Log.e("_start_at_device ", dateStartAt);
            Log.e("_start_at_diff ", String.valueOf(diff_Will_Start));
        }


        if (diff_Will_Start > 0) {
            offer_up_to.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.offer_start_at), dateStartAt));

            if (dateStartAt != null && dateStartAt.equals("null")) {
                offer_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }


        String inputDateEnd = DateUtils.prepareOutputDate(mOffer.getDate_end(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", this);
        long diff_will_end = DateUtils.getDiff(inputDateEnd, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");


        if (AppConfig.APP_DEBUG) {
            Log.e("_end_at_server", mOffer.getDate_end());
            Log.e("_end_at_device ", dateEndAt);
            Log.e("_end_at_diff ", String.valueOf(diff_will_end));

        }


        if (diff_will_end > 0 && diff_Will_Start < 0) {
            if (dateEndAt == null || dateEndAt.equals("null")) {
                offer_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                offer_up_to.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.offer_end_at), dateEndAt));
                offer_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }


        if (diff_Will_Start < 0 && diff_will_end < 0) {
            offer_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            offer_up_to.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.offer_ended_at), dateEndAt));
        }
```

Here is the DateUtils.java

```
package com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.AppController;
import com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.appconfig.AppConfig;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by Droideve on 8/17/2016.
 */

public class DateUtils {


    public static String getCurrentDay() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        return new SimpleDateFormat("EE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date.getTime()).toLowerCase();
    }


    public static String getPrepareSimpleDate(String inputDate, String outputSchema) {

        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputSchema, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {

            Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputDate);
            return outputFormat.format(date);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "N/A";
    }


    public static Long getDiff(String toyBornTime, String schema) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(schema);

        try {

            Date oldDate = dateFormat.parse(toyBornTime);
            Date currentDate = new Date();

            long diff = oldDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
            long seconds = diff / 1000;
            long minutes = seconds / 60;
            long hours = minutes / 60;
            long days = hours / 24;

            Log.e("oldDate", "" + oldDate.getTime() + " - " + dateFormat.format(oldDate.getTime()));
            Log.e("currentDate", "" + currentDate.getTime() + " - " + dateFormat.format(oldDate.getTime()));
            Log.e("Difference: ", " seconds: " + seconds + " minutes: " + minutes
                    + " hours: " + hours + " days: " + days);

            // Log.e("toyBornTime", "" + toyBornTime);

            return diff;

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Long.valueOf(0);
    }


    public static String getUTC(String schema) {

        Date myDate = new Date();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        calendar.setTime(myDate);
        Date time = calendar.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String dateAsString = outputFmt.format(time);

        return dateAsString;
    }


    public static String getLocalTime(String schema) {

        Date todayDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat outputFmt = new SimpleDateFormat(schema);
        return outputFmt.format(todayDate);

    }


    public static String getDateByTimeZone(String dateStr, String schema) {
        String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
        inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        Locale current = AppController.getInstance().getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        try {

            Date inputDate = inputFormat.parse(dateStr);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = null;

            if (schema != null) {
                if (AppConfig.APP_DEBUG)
                    Log.e("dateUtilsSchema", schema + " - " + current);
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(schema, current);
            } else {
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm", current);
            }

            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            return formatter.format(inputDate);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return dateStr;
        }
    }


    public static String prepareOutputDate(String dateStr, String schema, Context context) {

        String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm";

        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);

        try {

            inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            Date inputDate = inputFormat.parse(dateStr);

            String hourFormat = "hh:mm";

            if (context != null) {
                if (hourFormat12(context)) {
                    hourFormat = "hh:mm";
                } else {
                    hourFormat = "kk:mm";
                }
            }

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy " + hourFormat);
            SimpleDateFormat formatterHour = new SimpleDateFormat(hourFormat);

            if (schema != null) {
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(schema);
                formatterHour = new SimpleDateFormat(schema);
            }


            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            formatterHour.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

            int diffrence = minutesDifference(dateStr);

            if (diffrence < 1440) {
                return formatterHour.format(inputDate);
            } else {
                return formatter.format(inputDate);
            }


        } catch (ParseException e) {


            return dateStr;
        }

    }


    public static boolean isLessThan24(String dateString, String format) {

        try {

            SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s");
            inputFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date dateBegin = inputFormatter.parse(dateString);

            Date dateCurrent = new Date();


            long result = dateBegin.getTime() - dateCurrent.getTime();
            long days = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(result, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            long hours = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(result, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            if (AppConfig.APP_DEBUG) {
                Log.e("upcoming tz: ", TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
                Log.e("upcoming date: " + dateBegin + " days:", days + " " + result);
                Log.e("upcoming date: " + dateBegin + " hours:", hours + " " + result);
                Log.e("upcoming", "==================  ===================");
            }

            if (hours < 24 && hours >= 0) {
                return true;
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static int minutesDifference(String dateStr) {

        int MILLI_TO_MINUTE = 1000 * 60;
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s");

        Date currentDate = new Date();

        try {

            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date date = formatter.parse(dateStr);

            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            String newDate = formatter.format(date);
            date = formatter.parse(newDate);


            return (int) (currentDate.getTime() - date.getTime()) / MILLI_TO_MINUTE;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return 0;
    }


    private static boolean hourFormat12(Context context) {

        Calendar mCalendar = null;
        return !DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are passing a String with value "null" to your getDiff method...

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets break this down.

First your error log shows you where you need to be looking:

```
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "null"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
        at com.buzzr.ca.skeloo.utils.DateUtils.getDiff(DateUtils.java:56)
```

so on line 56 of your DateUtils class when you call dateFormat.parse the past in sting has the value null (and thus can be parsed).

Now we can look back over your code to figure out WHY it has that value.

In your OfferDetailActivity class the lines that are the issue is

```
String inputDateSatrt = DateUtils.prepareOutputDate(mOffer.getDate_start(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", this);
long diff_Will_Start = DateUtils.getDiff(inputDateSatrt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

SO the `inputDataSatrt` has the value of "null" for some reason, lets look into the `prepareOutputDate` method to find out why. At this point its also worth looking at your try block... why are you trying to set the string `dateStartAt` but then not using its value? You have code duplication here when you can be using the `dateStartAt`  value instead of having to call `prepareOutputDate` again.

Lets take a look at `prepareOutputDate` in your DateUtils.

Working backwards lets see if we can find why the returned string value is "null". Without knowing what the `Offer` class contains or what mOffer.getDate_end() returns this will be harder but we can assume that it does return.

Your class if it hits a ParseException (because for example the value of `dateStr` isnt in the right format will just return the value of dateStr... And expectation wont be thrown and your try block will continue. However in your `getDiff` class you print the Exception giving the error your seeing.

How you are handing Parse Exceptions is not coincident and so its safe to assume that mOffer.getDate_start() is returning "null"